# JDBC Connection Pooling for Servlets

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, connection-pooling

Currently I'm using a separate DBConnectionManager class to handle my connection pooling, but I also realized that this was the wrong way to go as the servlet was not calling the same pool each time a doGet() is performed.

1. Can someone explain to me why the above is happening?
2. Is JNDI the way to go for java servlets with tomcat for proper connection pooling?

I have links to 2 articles, is this the correct way to implement connection pooling with servlets?

http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200601/JDBCConnectionPooling.html

http://onjava.com/onjava/2006/04/19/database-connection-pooling-with-tomcat.html

Is it possible to save the db manager object in the context like so:

```
mtdb = (MTDbManager) context.getAttribute("MTDBMANAGER");
if (mtdb == null) {
            System.out
                    .println("MTDbManager is null, reinitialize MTDbManager");              

            initMTDB(config);
            context.setAttribute("MTDBMANAGER", mtdb);
        }
```

And then I call mtdb.getInstance().getConnection() and it will always reference this object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, the best advice is to leave the connection pooling to the application server.  Just look up the data source using JNDI, and let the application server handle the rest.  That makes your application portable (different application servers have different pooling mechanisms and settings) and most likely to be most efficient.

Comment: Just another question, does JNDI do proper connection pooling? Meaning I set max connections to 5, a 6th request comes in and JNDI will do a wait timeout before attempting to get a connection again.

Comment: JNDI itself does not do pooling, you look up a [`javax.sql.DataSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) object which gives you the `getConnection()` method which you'll call when you need a connection.  If there is no available connection, then the call to `getConnection()` will block.  N.B. you don't have to lookup the JNDI datasource every time you need a connection either, it is quite common practice to cache the reference to the data source. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at, and use, C3P0 instead of rolling your own solution: http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/